# Is there an efficient way to replace spaces with _ in filenames? (thousands of files)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a directory "FolderName" with 10,000 new files every day. Almost a half of those files are named as follows:

```
filename_yyyy-mm-dd_hh:mm
```

while the other half are named:

```
filename_yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm
```

(with space instead of underscore)

The script I'd like to set up should do the following:

Rename only the files containing a space in their name, skipping files that need no processing.

I cannot find a way to make the script efficient, I need to really skip the good half, my script tries to mv any file, and it's quite long and inefficient. Any good idea for a better design?

Thanks everybody

Comment: Can you show us your script as it looks right now?

Comment: if you have the rename tool, it will be easy.  There are many answers on this site already.

Comment: If you renamed all the files to the form of `yyyy-mm-dd_hh:mm_filename` you can easily sort and move the older ones. Or just sort using `-k` and compare to the date cutoff

Comment: Those are 2 completely different questions. I strongly recommend you pick 1 and follow the instructions at [ask] for that. Maybe focus on the first one since all of the answers and comments so far are about that and not your 2nd question.

Comment: Thanks Ed for your address. Is it allowed to edit a question whether answers become to appear? Or is it better to leave it as is? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for f in "$(find . -name '* *')"; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/\ /_/'); done` will do it. There should be a better way using find's `-exec` option as well.

EDIT:
If the function is put in a script, then find can be used directly:

```
cat <<EOF > space_to_underscore
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mv "$1" "$(sed 's/\ /_/' <(echo "$1"))"
EOF
chmod +x space_to_underscore

find . -name '* *' -exec ./space_to_underscore {} \;
```

This will be faster than using a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL) utility, a Perl script designed just for this, it's powerful and fast.

```
rename -n ' ' _ *\ *
```

Or:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name '* *' -exec rename -n ' ' _ {} \;
```

The `-n` flag is for dry run, to print what works happen without actually renaming anything. If the output looks good, remove the flag and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

with the legacy `rename` you can easily convert single space to underlines

```
$ rename ' ' '_' files
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename only the files containing a space in their name, skipping files that need no processing:

```
for file in *\ * ; do mv "$file" "${file// /_}" ; done
```

Move all the files older than one week to a "NewFolderName" folder:

```
find -mtime 7 -exec mv {} NewFolderName/ \;
```